# iOS - iPad preview in Xcode is missing

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ipad

I don't know how can I bring iPad in xcode preview? Right now It is missing. I have checked that all simulator is listed in `xcode > Windows > Devices`, and my app is set as `Universal` in `Deployment info`. Currently my xcode version is `Version 7.3.1 (7D1014)`.

If anyone knows, please share with me. Any kind of suggestoin is very much appreciable. Thanks a lot in advance.

Let me attach a screen shot of it.

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For the getting list of all devices size preview, first you need Enabling `Size Classes` in [Interface Builder](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/EnablingAdaptiveSizeDesign.html). As per following screenshot you just need to check right mark in `File Inspector`.

[image]

After enabling size classes now check the preview. You get the full list of all devices.

[image]

So without `sizeClass` that wont appear the iPad list

Let me show you real time GIF:

[image]

Comment: Shuu, what a bummer. I don't know how that size class option got unselect. Yes, I got it. Thanks for the direction. It's perfect. :)

Comment: @Nitin Gohel can i display ipad without select autolayout

Comment: by the way if you check sizeClass then that auto layout by default select so size class is necessary. i just test that sample code without sizeclass and with use size class. in xcode7.3

Answer (score 3):

Now in Xcode9 you can get the list of all devices by enabling "Use Trait Variations"

[image]